# Yii 1.14 controller from two parts in module produce 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii, http-status-code-404

i have yii project hosted on Godaddy, i created admin panel as a separated module called "admin", the admin panel works fine in my localhost but when i moved the code to my host all Admin module controllers from two parts example "subCategoryController" stopped working and returns a 404 error, all other controllers that consists from only one part working fine example "user,post,...", they all working fine on my localhost the problem only on my host in godaddy.
this is some code snippets that i am using in my htaccess and main.php :

main.php :

urlManager :

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(              
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

.htaccess

```
Options  +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php 
</IfModule>
```

Example of Url that i can access :
somewebsite.com/admin/user/index

Example of Url i can't access on godaddy but i can access it on my localhost :
somewebsite.com/admin/subCategory/index

This what i tried so far and didn't work :

1- adding static rule like this :

```
'/admin/sub-category' => '/admin/subCategory/index'
```

2- add module rewriting rules :

```
 '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/view',
                                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

please let me know if you need more information, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into this problem a couple times before. It seems to stem from case-based differences in controller names. I normally try to keep my controller names like `SomethingController.php` (so, first letter of filename and `C` in controller is caps, and nothing else) to avoid those differences between environments.

Comment: From now on i gonna do as you mentioned in my controllers but i think there should be a solution for this problem between different environments, regards.

Comment: @MSost is correct here. As the lower and upper case characters have different ASCII value, case-sensitivity is a better practice for environment independent code. Yii uses it for resolving the filenames. Windows may have not needed much options to use but Unix/Linux does.

Comment: @KunalDethe At the moment i did as @M Sost mentioned since i need to complete my work on the project thanks to him to mention that solution, the problem is that the two parts problem appears only in modules but in normal app they don't, i have ajax controller from two parts and it works fine out of the module and i disabled the case sensitive in my app, regards.