# Yii app uploaded on host brings up a 404 error when I call a specific action

Tags: php, yii

I am developing my app using xampp, and everything works fine there. But when I upload it on a host (hostinger) and try accessing a specific page I get a 404 error.

The button linking me to that page (from a different controller) has this as a url:

```
array('url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("symptomHistory/patientSymptomHistory",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
```

(it's a button in a gridview)

The action that it calls is the following:

```
public function actionPatientSymptomHistory($id)
{
    //create model doctor request and search the database for a doctor request between the doctor user and 
    //the patient user
    $doctorRequestModel = new DoctorRequests;
    $doctorPatientRequest = $doctorRequestModel->findByAttributes(array('doctorID'=>Yii::app()->user->id, 'userID'=>$id, 'doctorAccepted'=>1));
    //if there is an accepted doctor request between doctor and patient, show the patients's symptom history
    if(isset($doctorPatientRequest))
    {   
        $model = new Symptomhistory;


        //model for the patients data
        $patientModel = User::model()->findByPk($id);
        //empty array to store all the user's symptoms
        $symptomItems = array();
        //find all symptomHistory records belonging to the user
        $symptomHistoryModels = $model->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$id));
        //loop through all the symptomHistory records that belong to the user
        foreach($symptomHistoryModels as $symptom)
        {
            //switch case for event color. set color for each flag type
            switch($symptom->symptomFlag)
            {
                case '1':
                    $symptomColor = '#A1EB86';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $symptomColor = '#CCCA52';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $symptomColor = '#F25138';
                    break;
                default:
                    $symptomColor = '#36c';
            }
            //create event
            $symptomItem=array('title'=>$symptom->symptomTitle,
                                'start'=>$symptom->dateSymptomFirstSeen,
                                'end'=>$symptom->dateSearched,
                                'symptomCode'=>$symptom->symptomCode,
                                'symptomHistoryID'=>$symptom->id,
                                'flag'=>$symptom->symptomFlag,
                                'color'=>$symptomColor
            );
            //copy symptomHistory event into array
            array_push($symptomItems, $symptomItem);
        }
        //render patient history
        $this->render('patientSymptomHistory',array(
            'model'=> $model, 'patientModel'=> $patientModel, 'symptomHistoryEvents'=>$symptomItems
        ));
    }
    else //else throw exception
    {
        throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not permitted to check this patient\'s Symptom History');
    }
}
```

(sorry for the extra long code, but I honestly have no idea what might help and what might not).

I repeat I get a 404 error, not  a 403 one.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What's the controller name? Could be the name of your controller that's the problem. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916671/yii-1-14-controller-from-two-parts-in-module-produce-404-error#comment40593480_25916671

Comment: woohoo, that was it. Now post your comment as an answer so I can give you some rep you lovely person :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to this question here: [Yii 1.14 controller from two parts in module produce 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916671/yii-1-14-controller-from-two-parts-in-module-produce-404-error#comment40593480_25916671)

Differences between environments can lead to 404s of this nature, due to naming conventions with controllers. Since upper case and lower case characters have different ASCII values, certain environments will evaluate them differently.

In my experience, naming controllers following this pattern: `FooController.php`, where the first letter  and the "C" in Controller are capitalized and nothing else, seems to work in all environments.