# Error 404 Unable to resolve the request in Yii (checked other solution but not work)

Tags: php, yii

I got this error:

```
Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "PlanComment/update".
```

It works well on local but not work on server.
I also changed case sensitivity but still not work.
Here is my code:

PlanCommentController.php

```
class PlanCommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

```
/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
       //   'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('update', 'delete'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

....

View file: _comment.php

```
    $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
                          'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'dropup'),
                          'buttons' => array(
                                array('items' => array(
                                    array('label' => 'Delete Comment', 'url' => array('PlanComment/delete',            'id'=>$comment->id, 'plan_id'=>$comment->plan_id),
                                           'visible'=>(Yii::app()->user->id == $comment->user_id) ||   Yii::app()->user->isPlanAuthor($comment->plan_id)),
                                    '---',
                                    array('label' => 'Edit Comment', 'url' => array('PlanComment/update', 'id'=>$comment->id, 'plan_id'=>$comment->plan_id),
                                            'visible'=>(Yii::app()->user->id == $comment->user_id)),
                      )),),)); ?>
```

Config file: main.php

// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
            'urlManager'=>array(
                    'urlFormat'=>'path',
        // remove index.php
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
                    'rules'=>array(
            'home'=>'site/index',
            'plan'=>'plan/index',
            'video'=>'video/index',
            'login/<service:(google|google-oauth|yandex|yandex-oauth|twitter|linkedin|vkontakte|facebook|steam|yahoo|mailru|moikrug|github|live|odnoklassniki)>' => 'site/login',
            '<action:(login|register|logout|about)>' => 'site/<action>',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<ten>_<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/update/<ten>_<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/update',
                            '<controller:\w+>/view_thanhvien/<ten>_<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view_thanhvien',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    ),
            ),

Where is wrong in my code ?
Please help.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027289/yii-app-uploaded-on-host-brings-up-a-404-error-when-i-call-a-specific-action/26027603#26027603). Generally you want to avoid multiple capital letters within controller names other than the first letter of the controller name and the "C" in "Controller".

Comment: I tried some ways at below but still not work:
1. PlancommentController.php
    class PlancommentController extends Controller
   'url' => array('Plancomment/delete',
------------
2. plancommentController.php
    class plancommentController extends Controller
    'url' => array('plancomment/delete',
-----------
3. PlancommentController.php
    class PlancommentController extends Controller
    'url' => array('planComment/delete',

Comment: Oh yeah. It works now. Thank you M Sost.
My mistask about git commit.
Work in below case:  PlancommentController.php; class PlancommentController extends Controller;  'url' => array('plancomment/delete',

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be like `"planComment/update"` instead of `"PlanComment/update".`
**The first letter of controller name must be lower case**.

Comment: I think the problem is your url-manager rules. Try to use my suggestion always(because this is a good practice). Next try to remove all url-manager rules(except default rules). If problem solved, you can change your url-manager rules.

Comment: Thanks @hamed. I tried with M Sost's advice. It works well now.